# O que são os princípios DRY, KISS e YAGNI?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, princípios-de-programação

Esses três princípios (DRY, KISS e YAGNI) são amplamente citados na *web*.

O que são? Quem os criou? Como e onde podem ser aplicados?

Comment: O link [desta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23063/101) é o que tem de melhor em todas as respostas. Ler simplificações pode causar entendimento totalmente errado do DRY. O mesmo vale para os outros princípios. Por isso nem sei se perguntar 3 coisas diferentes é a melhor estratégia. Seria se estivesse perguntando a relação entre eles. É uma pena que a questão mais importante não foi respondida diretamente: **Como podem ser aplicados?** O resto acha fácil na internet. Estou um pouco sem tempo agora e não achei uma forma legal, se achar eu respondo esta parte.

Comment: Respondi sobre DRY aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**DRY — Don’t Repeat Yourself**

Se você usa muitas repetições, você não tem total conhecimento do assunto, ou seja você está enrolando. Pensar em apenas não repetir o código não significa que você está usando plenamente o **DRY**, temos que trabalhar em cima da lógica também.

```
describe "Person#full_name" do
it "concats the first and last names" do
first_name = "John"
last_name = "Doe"
person = Person.new(:first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name)
person.full_name.should eq "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
end
```

Acima está o uso da filosofia DRY e abaixo não.

```
describe "Person#full_name" do
it "concats the first and last names" do
person = Person.new(:first_name => "John", :last_name => "Doe")
person.full_name.should eq "John Doe"
end
end
```

Mas segundo **David Chelimsky** (http://www.infoq.com/br/news/2012/07/DRY-acoplamento-duplicacao), seguir isto religiosamente pode talvez prejudicar a legibilidade do código.

**YAGNI — You Ain't Gonna Need It**

Está é a filosofia do **Você não vai precisar dele**, muitas vezes eu coloquei funções que no momento não eram necessárias em meu sistema, então o que começou a acontecer? Pessoas ligando e perguntando."Para que serve isto?". Além do retrabalho de ter que atender as pessoas e retirar ou desabilitar a visualização isto pode trazer um processamento a mais sem necessidade. Já ouvi muitas pessoas dizendo: *"O que realmente é necessário?"* Vai uma dica abaixo:

"Se é barato fazer agora e barato depois, deixe para depois. Se é barato agora, mas ficará caríssimo depois, faça agora."(http://seiti.eti.br/blog/2010/kiss-yagni-e-dry)

**KISS – Keep It Simple, Stupid**

Aqui onde trabalho tenho um colega que tem muitos anos de algorítimos, ele desenvolvia `MUMPS`, o apelido dele é Jacaré, vou dizer para ele entrar no stackoverflow, não sei se ele vai querer, mas tudo bem. Ele sempre me ensinou que nós devemos fazer o simples, interessante é ver pelo lado do cliente, até porque trabalhei um período da minha vida como suporte. O cliente não sabe o que está por trás de uma tela bonita, ele simplesmente quer ver tudo funcionando e porquê complicar e inventar a roda quando podemos fazer o simples em tempo recorde e com uma lógica boa. O Jacaré sempre fala em fazer o simples, mas sempre faz um código doido.

Certamente vai haver pessoas que descordem destas filosofias, mas a minha dica principal é:

Tudo que é demais, faz mal.

Answer (score 12):

São algumas regras básicas para tornar o seu trabalho mais fácil, principalmente no que diz respeito a manutenção.

O significado de cada um é:

- **DRY:** *Don't Repeat Yourself*. Não repita a si mesmo. Suponha que o esforço para se corrigir um bug, para um programador normal, é X. Para um programador que copia e cola o mesmo código em várias partes diferentes do programa, o esforço é X vezes a quantidade de cópias do mesmo trecho.

Tem gente que diz que programar é parecido com compor música. Isso não é desculpa pra você meter um refrão no seu código.

- **KISS:** *Kids In Satan's Service*. Alguns professores de engenharia de software também dizem que significa *Keep It Simple, Stupid*, que significa manter o seu código o mais simples possível. [A autoria dessa versão é geralmente atribuída a um engenheiro da Lockheed.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#Origin)

Os dois códigos abaixo, em Javascript, fazem a mesma coisa:

```
// código escrito por um moleque, a mando de satã
var result = 2;
var temp = result;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    result *= temp;
}
if (result == 0) result = 1; // tratando exponenciação por zero
```

e

```
// código que não reinventa a roda, fácil de ler e que resolve o problema
Math.pow(2, 5);
```

Em qual você prefere dar manutenção?

- [**YAGNI:** *You Aren't Gonna Need It*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI). Literalmente, "você não vai precisar disso". <strike>É uma forma de dizer que se um código não faz nada, dê-lhe um uso ou o elimine do repositório. Eu gosto de aplicar também a comentários que não são úteis.</strike> Significa que você não deve se dar ao trabalho de codificar alguma coisa, até que realmente precise dela. Se você for codificar algo porque **acha** que vai precisar mais pra frente, pode acabar descobrindo que na verdade não precisava, e aí o tempo que você gastou com o componente foi perdido. (obrigado aí ao Casali e ao Omni pela correção!)

Comment: "Kids In Satan's Service"?!! De onde você tirou isso? rsrs A segunda definição ("Keep It Simple, Stupid") é a mais comumente utilizada [nessa área].

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu também não sabia dessa. Acho que não tem nada a ver com programação.

Comment: esse "Kids in Satan's Service" é qualquer coisa eheh. Não concordo com a sua definição de YAGNI. Não quer dizer que se algo não faz nada elimine-o, mas sim, não invente soluções para problemas que ainda não [tem](http://blog.codinghorror.com/kiss-and-yagni/)

Comment: Kids In Satan's Service é uma brincadeira com uma lenda urbana relacionada a uma das melhores bandas do mundo. Senso de humor, desenvolvedores!

Comment: @Renan não vá ouvir os discos deles ao contrário hein!

Answer (score 10):

## **DRY**

Don't Repeat Yourself: É muuito popular na comunidade e para quem desenvolve com Ruby / Rails, parte do princípio fundamental que NUNCA se deve repetir algo que já está criado. Aí entra o nome (Não repita você mesmo!). Ou seja defina um método, propriedade em um só lugar e reaproveite-o, em qualquer outro!!. Olha o exemplo que a [wiki na página do rails](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) dá:

> Por exemplo, ao invés de ter uma tabela Pessoas e uma classe Pessoa, com uma propriedade, um método "leitor" (getter) e um "modificador" (setter) para cada campo na tabela, tem-se apenas no banco de dados. As propriedades e métodos necessários são "injetados" na classe através de funcionalidades da linguagem Ruby.

## **KISS**

Não conheço muito bem a definição, mas pelo que vi é o seguinte. Como o próprio nome (sigla) diz você dever manter isso simples, `Keep it simple, stupid!`, (inclusive alguns autores usam sem a vírgula ou com, acabou por não terem um padrão para isso!), enfim toda e qualquer complexidade "deve" ser evitada, ou seja não tem por que ser complexo se pode ser simples!

## **YAGNI**

Este princípio diz que você só deve implementar algo, QUANDO REALMENTE VAI UTILIZÁ-LO, não quando você acha que vai utilizá-lo mais adiante!

Os nomes são bem sugestivos e os princípios são muito simples, mas que no dia-dia, quem consegue implementá-los do jeito certo, tem um código ágil, simples, eficaz e bonito!!
Fica as fontes (wikiiii!) para você entrar em mais detalhes em cada um deles!

fontes:

1. [wikipédia dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
2. [wikipédia kiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)
3. [wikipédia yagni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)