# Obter variáveis do self de outra classe e evento personalizado

Tags: python, classes, eventos

Leiam apenas comentários em português, a questão do self está em comentários no código, agora os eventos vai estar lá em baixo.

```
class LOL:
    class Champions:
        class MasterYi:
            def __init__(self):
                #YiAttributes
                self.YiAD = 66
                self.YiLevel = 1
                self.YiQ = 25 + self.YiAD

            def Name(self):
                return 'MasterYi'

            class Q:
                def Use(self, target):
                    print( "[MasterYi] Q In %s" % ( target ) )
                def Damage(self):
                    return self.YiQ #Como Eu Conseguiria Pegar O self.YiQ Da Classe MasterYi ?

        class Zed:
            def __init__(self):
                #ZedAttributes
                self.ZedAD = 84
                self.ZedLevel = 1
                self.ZedQ = 75 + self.ZedAD

            def Name(self):
                return 'Zed'

            class Q:
                def Use(self, target):
                    print( "[Zed] Q In %s" % ( target ) )
                def Damage(self):
                    return self.ZedQ #Mesmo Caso Do self.YiQ

    class Match:
        def Start(self, Tuple):
            print( "------ Starting Match ------\n" )
            if (len(Tuple) == 1):
                print( "Champions: %s" % ( Tuple[0].Name() ) )
            elif (len(Tuple) == 2):
                print( "Champions: %s, %s" % ( Tuple[0].Name(), Tuple[1].Name() ) )

        def Finish(self):
            print( "\n------ Finishing Match ------" )

#Creating Objects
Match = LOL.Match()
MasterYi = LOL.Champions.MasterYi()
Zed = LOL.Champions.Zed()

#Starting
Match.Start( ( MasterYi, Zed ) )

MasterYi.Q().Use( Zed.Name() )
print( "YiQ Damage: %g" % ( MasterYi.Q().Damage() ) )

#Finishing
Match.Finish()
```

Eu precisaria de um evento dentro da classe MasterYi que fizesse com que toda vez que a variável self.YiLevel fosse incrementada em 1, variáveis como self.YiAD e outras que não botei aqui no código, fossem aumentadas em valores específicos.

Deixei a parte da criação dos objetos no código porque ai vocês já podem pegar e testar o código.

E também como é eu que faço a incrementação de `self.YiLevel` no código, eu poderia junto já fazer a incrementação nas outras variáveis junto, só que no futuro, neste código, eu vou precisar saber fazer eventos personalizados querendo ou não, então já prefiro fazer uma pergunta com um exemplo mais simples.

Outro detalhe essas duas classes 'MasterYi' e 'Zed' são parecidas, mas vão existir mais outras dezenas de classes e garanto que a maioria vai ser diferente, nessas duas o calculo de self.Q funciona quase do mesmo jeito, só que em outras classes vai ser por exemplo self.Q = 30 + self.AP outras iram fazer cálculos de porcentagem tipo self.Q = self.AP * 30 / 100 + self.AD * 10 / 100.
**Então** nem sempre vai ser (algum número + o AD), ainda tem a questão de que n é só `Q` e sim (Q, W, E, R)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está repetindo a mesma coisa para múltiplas classes, dê uma olhada no principio `DRY — Don’t Repeat Yourself`, já foi respondida uma pergunta aqui no [SOPt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23052/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-princ%C3%ADpios-dry-kiss-e-yagni)

### Magicas

Primeiramente criei uma classe `Magic`, onde `Q`, `E`, `W` e `R` são *filhas*. Cada filha filha possui sua classe, ou seja, você pode definir métodos exclusivos para cada e, incorporar os métodos `Use` e `Damage` da super classe `Magic`.

```
class Magic:

    def __init__(self, magic, source, power):
        self.magic = magic
        self.source = source
        self.power = power

    def Use(self, target):
        print("{source} {magic} In {target}".format(source=self.source, magic=self.magic, target=target))

    def Damage(self):
        return self.power

class Q(Magic, object):

    def __init__(self, source, ad, power):
        power = power + ad
        Magic.__init__(self, 'Q', source, power)

# W, E, R ....
```

E outra classe `Magics` onde irá **agrupar** todas as filhas.

```
class Magics:

    def __init__(self, source, ad, q, w, e, r):
        self.Q = Q(source, ad, q)
        self.W = W(source, ad, w)
        self.E = E(source, e)
        self.R = R(source, ad, r)
```

### Champions

A classe incorpora os atributos da classe `Magics`

```
class Champion:

    def __init__(self, name, ad, level, powerQ, powerW, powerE, powerR):
        self.name = name
        self.ad = ad
        self.level = level
        self.powerQ = powerQ
        self.powerW = powerW
        self.powerE = powerE
        self.powerR = powerR

        self.Magics = Magics(self.name, self.ad, self.powerQ, powerW, powerE, powerR)
```

Para utilizar as mágicas por personagem, basta utilizar: *Personagem*.Magics.*Magica*.*Método*

```
MasterYi.Magics.Q.Use(Zed.name)
```

Veja o resultado final no [ideone](http://ideone.com/FSrjqC)

Comment: Mas a ideia de não repetir o código eu entendi. é um problema classe dentro de classe ou tanto faz ?

Comment: E também tem a seguinte questão nem todos os 'champions' o `Q` funcionam assim: Q = Q + AD
alguns vão ser Q = Q + AD * 30 / 100, outros Q = Q + AP
cada (Q, W, E, R) de cada 'champion' vai ser diferente.

Comment: Então será um valor diferente para cada magia? Por exemplo `ZedQ`, `ZedW`, `ZedE`...? @axell13

Comment: Sim só que nem todas magias são de dano como por exemplo o ZedW é uma skill que lança um sombra q imita o ZedQ e o ZedE, o YiW É uma magia que recupera vida ao longo de 4 segundos. Cada magia quase sempre vai ser tratada diferente, mas nem todas como por exemplo o YiQ e ZedQ todas duas são o dano base da magia 25, 75 respectivamente + o AD.

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se é o que precisa. @axell13

Comment: E quanto a questão do `Q` em outros personagens ? Como eu disse as vezes pode ser power = power + ((ad * 30) / 100) ou power = power + ((ap * 80) / 100) ou outros cálculos.

Eu prefiro copiar a classe por exemplo do MasterYi (do meu código) e ir adaptando os cálculos das mágias para cada um.

Comment: Eu não criar um(a) função/construtor(`__init__`) passando uma string que seria o calculo, porque são mais de 120 champions, não tem como eu lembrar o calculo de cada, principalmente porque não é 120 é 120 * 4 (Q,W,E,R), ai eu teria que ficar olhando toda hora.

Comment: E também tem a questão de que nem todos Q,W,E,R tem dano, alguns dão atributos com penetração de armadura, dano verdadeiro, velocidade de ataque, armadura e etc, você está lendo os comentários que estou escrevendo ? parece que não.

Comment: Acho que você quer o código pronto, com certeza você terá que adaptar o código como preferir de acordo com sua necessidade, estou fazendo um favor. Pra cada problema que você citou existe uma solução, basta pensar! Abraços @axell13

Comment: ok prefiro fazer as classes do jeito que estava mesmo, prefiro copiar uma classe e adaptar os cálculos das magias acho mais fácil.

Comment: Principalmente porque não quero passar toda hora os parâmetros como por exemplo ad, ap, level e etc, afinal cada champion vai ser diferente. Já quero ter eles prontos, quero facilidade no futuro, por isso eu monto as classes,
invez de passar parâmetros só crio o objeto do meu champion, pronto.

Comment: Chegou a olhar o [ideone](http://ideone.com/FSrjqC)? No final tem uma classe `LOL`, onde já defino os champions.. Você prefere criar 120 champions e inserir manualmente todas os métodos, variaveis, onde boa parte é o mesmo codigo? Já pensou futuramente como será difícil a manutenção desse código?.... @axell13

Comment: o único problema mesmo é a questão da aleatoriedade nos cálculos de cada Champion (Essa não sei o que fazer)...

Comment: Se o código é Python2 e não Python3, não esqueça que as classes tem _todas_ que herdar de "object"