# Show / Hide div ao clicar no menu

Tags: javascript

Boas, eu estou com um problema no código, pretendo ao carregar num botão do Menu que esconda todas as DIV excepto uma,no entanto não está a resultar, alguém me pode ajudar por favor?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 84.8%;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3db2e1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #dff2fa;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: #dff2fa;
  background: #19799f;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a::before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  border-top: 2px solid #dff2fa;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dff2fa;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  background: #dff2fa;
}

video#bgvid {
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
}


html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
 left: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 80%;
 border: 0px solid #165480;
}

#cima{
 width: 99%;
 position: absolute;
 
}

#logo{
    width: 40%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10%;
 top: 2%;
}

#sect1{
 border: 1px solid #165480;
 width: 80%;
 height: 75%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10%;
 top: 15%;
 background-color: #eef9ff;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#sect2{
 border: 1px solid #165480;
 width: 80%;
 height: 75%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10%;
 top: 15%;
 background-color: #eef9ff;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#sect3{
 border: 1px solid #165480;
 width: 80%;
 height: 75%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10%;
 top: 15%;
 background-color: #eef9ff;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#sect4{
 border: 1px solid #165480;
 width: 80%;
 height: 75%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10%;
 top: 15%;
 background-color: #eef9ff;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#sect5{
 border: 1px solid #165480;
 width: 80%;
 height: 75%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10%;
 top: 15%;
 background-color: #eef9ff;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
 
#menu{
 position: absolute;
 left: 48%;
 top: 30px;
 width:50%;
}

body,td,th {
 font-size: 12px;
}

.sombra
{
text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MDG - Empresa</title>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="mdg.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").click(function(event){
   var link = $(this);    
   if(link.attr("id").match("menuinicio"))
   $("#sect1").show("slow");
   $("#sect2").hide("slow");
   $("#sect3").hide("slow");
   $("#sect4").hide("slow");
   $("#sect5").hide("slow");
   else if(link.attr("id").match("menuempresa"))
   $("#sect2").show("slow");
   $("#sect1").hide("slow");
   $("#sect3").hide("slow");
   $("#sect4").hide("slow");
   $("#sect5").hide("slow");
   else if(link.attr("id").match("menuprodutos"))
   $("#sect3").show("slow");
   $("#sect1").hide("slow");
   $("#sect2").hide("slow");
   $("#sect4").hide("slow");
   $("#sect5").hide("slow");
   else if(link.attr("id").match("menuempresa"))
   $("#sect4").show();
   $("#sect1").hide();
   $("#sect2").hide();
   $("#sect3").hide();
   $("#sect5").hide();
   else
   $("#sect5").show("slow");
   $("#sect1").hide("slow");
   $("#sect2").hide("slow");
   $("#sect3").hide("slow");
   $("#sect4").hide("slow");
  });
 })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
<source src="media/mdg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="cima">
<div id="logo">
<img src="media/logo.png" alt="MetalurgiaDulceGavina" title="MetalurgiaDulceGavina" width="199" height="73">
</div>
<div id="menu">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'>
   <li id="menuinicio"><a href='#'>Inicio</a></li>
   <li id="menuempresa"><a href='#'>Empresa</a></li>
   <li id="menuprodutos"><a href='#'>Produtos</a></li>
   <li id="menunoticias"><a href='#'>Noticias</a></li>
   <li id="menucontacto"><a href='#'>Contactos</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="sect2"><p>2</p></div>
<div id="sect3"><p>3</p></div>
<div id="sect4"><p>4</p></div>
<div id="sect5"><p>5</p></div>
<div id="sect1"><p>1</p></div>
<footer align="center">
      <pre><small><strong><u>Copyright© 2015 MDG - Metalurgia Dulce Gavina, Unipessoal, Lda.</u></strong></small></pre>
      <pre class="sombra"><strong>Something</strong></pre>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tens de ler sobre [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23052/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-princ%C3%ADpios-dry-kiss-e-yagni), que é uma regra/recomendação sobre a importancia de não repetir código desnecessáriamente.

Se juntares essa ideia ao facto de `if`s sem `{}` só se aplicarem á linha imediatamente a seguir, então podes simplificar o teu código para algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var paginas = {
        menuinicio: '#sect1',
        menuempresa: '#sect2',
        menuprodutos: '#sect3',
        menunoticias: '#sect4'
    }
    $(".active li").click(function (event) {
        $('[id^="sect"]').hide('slow');
        $(paginas[this.id] || '#sect5').show('slow');
    });
});
```

Repara que tens um erro de sintaxe no teu HTML, onde tens

```
<ul>
   <li class='active'>
   <li id="menuinicio"><a href='#'>Inicio</a></li>
```

sendo que esse `<li class='active'>` não deve ter outro `li` dentro, mas mais grave é que não está fechado. Ou seja falta o `</li>`.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5paxq6at/show/

Answer (score 0):

O erro que vi aí que tu está usando `String.match` como comparação `if`.

O método `String.match(RegEx)` server para testar se a string casa com a expressão regular ([Documentação aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match))

Então se tu substituir esta linha:

```
if(link.attr("id").match("menuinicio"))
```

por:

```
if( link.attr("id") === "menuinicio" )
```

Provavelmente vai dar certo.

Mas eu proponho usar uma abordagem diferente.

Use classes para controlar os items que serão mostrados ou escondidos.
Ex.:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-target="#menuinicio"><a href='#'>Inicio</a></li>
    <li data-target="#menuempresa"><a href='#'>Empresa</a></li>
    <li data-target="#menuprodutos"><a href='#'>Produtos</a></li>
    <li data-target="#menunoticias"><a href='#'>Noticias</a></li>
    <li data-target="#menucontacto"><a href='#'>Contactos</a></li>
</ul>
...
<ul id="content-container">
    <li id="menuinicio" class="active"><a href='#'>Inicio</a></li>
    <li id="menuempresa"><a href='#'>Empresa</a></li>
    <li id="menuprodutos"><a href='#'>Produtos</a></li>
    <li id="menunoticias"><a href='#'>Noticias</a></li>
    <li id="menucontacto"><a href='#'>Contactos</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
// Faz cache do elemento para não precisar transpor a  DOMTree mais que uma vez
var content_container = $('#content-container');

$('#menu').find('li').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    content_container
        .find('active') // encontra a tab ativa atual
        .removeClass('active') // remove a classe 'active'
        .hide('slow'); // esconde ela
    content_container
        .find($this.data('target')) // encontra a tab em que o menu "aponta"
        .addClass('active') // torna ela a aba ativa
        .show('slow'); // mostra a tab
});
```

Tentei manter tua lógica, mas acho que tu deveria mostrar e esconder tuas tabs por CSS. Algo como:

```
#content-container > li {
    display: none;
}

#content-container > li.active {
    display: block;
}
```

E talvez usar algumas [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) para dar mais efeito.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui fica uma outra variante para o futuro (IE9+), só com CSS, sem JavaScript.

Muda o HTML para ter no `href` de cada link do menu o `id` da `div` que queres mostrar. Depois juntas no CSS desses `li a`:

```
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 1s;
```

e finalmente:

```
:target {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

ou para ser mais específico:

```
#sect1:target, #sect2:target, #sect3:target, #sect4:target, #sect5:target {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s24dpzrx/show/