# Inverter ordem dos nomes em inputs?

Tags: javascript, array, input

Estou tentando fazer um exercício onde tenho que pegar 5 nomes em 5 input diferentes, armazená-los em um array e imprimi-los nos mesmos campos mas na ordem inversa ao que estavam.

```
function inverteNomes(){

    var nome1 = document.getElementById("txtNome0").value;
    var nome2 = document.getElementById("txtNome1").value;
    var nome3 = document.getElementById("txtNome2").value;
    var nome4 = document.getElementById("txtNome3").value;
    var nome5 = document.getElementById("txtNome4").value;

    var arrayNomes = [nome1, nome2, nome3, nome4, nome5];
    var invertido = arrayNomes.reverse();   

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var nome = document.getElementById("txtNome" + i);
        nome.innerHTML = invertido[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta do Rafael já aponta o problema, aqui fica uma sugestão para ser mais [DRY](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/129): http://jsfiddle.net/hkco5c00/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue exemplo prático.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      function inverso(){
        var nome1 = document.getElementById("txtNome0").value;
        var nome2 = document.getElementById("txtNome1").value;
        var nome3 = document.getElementById("txtNome2").value;
        var nome4 = document.getElementById("txtNome3").value;
        var nome5 = document.getElementById("txtNome4").value;

        var arrayNomes = [nome5, nome4, nome3, nome2, nome1];   

        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            document.getElementById("txtNome"+i+"").value = arrayNomes[i];
        }
    }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtNome0"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="txtNome1"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="txtNome2"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="txtNome3"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="txtNome4"/><br/><br/>

    <input type="button" value="Inverter" onclick="inverso();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rodrigo, eu acho a outra resposta melhor por explicar o problema com texto. Se juntares isso à tua resposta (ie porque o código do AP não funcionou) vou dar `+1` também na tua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite, seu programa não está funcionando porque você está tentando mudar o valor de um input usando a propriedade `innerHTML`, a propriedade certa para isso é a `value`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var nome = document.getElementById("txtNome" + i);
  nome.value = invertido[i];
}
```

Veja o programa funcionando: http://codepen.io/raftelti/pen/VvwWBP?editors=101