# Pegar o Indice correto sem duplicar o Option do Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso criar um `select` com os dias da semana, e  carregá-los quando já estiverem no banco de dados, então eu recebo no meu index o `id` do dia da semana e tenho que deixar ele como `selected`, eu estou fazendo assim, porém o mesmo fica duplicado.

```js
$("body").append(diasHorario(2)); // seleciona Terça

function diasHorario(index) {
  var dias = Array('Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo');

  var result = "<select id='diasHorario' class='form-control'>" +
    "<option value=" + index + "> " + dias[index - 1] + "</option>" +
    "<option value='1'>Segunda</option>" +
    "<option value='2'>Terça</option>" +
    "<option value='3'>Quarta</option>" +
    "<option value='4'>Quinta</option>" +
    "<option value='5'>Sexta</option>" +
    "<option value='6'>Sábado</option>" +
    "<option value='7'>Domingo</option>" +
    "</select>";
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa o [.selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)  que faz exatamente isso: escolhe o index da `option` selecionada, atribuido o numero desejado a essa propriedade. 
Nota que o index começa em `0`, então podes usar simplesmente:

```
select.selectedIndex = index - 1;
```

O código todo seria assim, e usando boas práticas de não misturar HTML no meio de JavaScript:

```
$("body").append(diasHorario(2)); // seleciona Terça

function diasHorario(index) {

    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.id = 'diasHorario';
    select.classList.add('form-control');

    var dias = ['Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'];
    dias.forEach(function (dia, i) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = i + 1;
        option.innerHTML = dia;
        select.appendChild(option);
    });

    select.selectedIndex = index - 1;
    return select;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xb08pzd/

Se quiseres manter o padrão de *string* no retorno dessa função podes usar uma destas alternativas:

**#1** - http://jsfiddle.net/2xb08pzd/4/  (JS puro)

**#2** - http://jsfiddle.net/2xb08pzd/6/ (concatenando HTML)

```
function diasHorario(index) {
    var dias = Array('Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo');
    return dias.reduce(function (str, dia, i) {
        return str + ['<option value="', i + 1, '" ', i == index - 1 ? 'selected="selected"' : '', '>', dia, '</option>'].join('')
    }, "<select id='diasHorario' class='form-control'>") + "</select>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Está repetindo porque você está deixando fixo na primeira posição o dia selecionado.

O que você deve fazer é verificar em cada item se o valor passado é igual ao index do dia.

Segue exemplo:

```js
$("body").append(diasHorario(2)); // seleciona Terça

function diasHorario(index) {
  var dias = Array('Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo');

  var result = "<select id='diasHorario' class='form-control'>" +
    "<option value='1'" + (index == 1 ? "selected" : "") + ">Segunda</option>" +
    "<option value='2'" + (index == 2 ? "selected" : "") + ">Terça</option>" +
    "<option value='3'" + (index == 3 ? "selected" : "") + ">Quarta</option>" +
    "<option value='4'" + (index == 4 ? "selected" : "") + ">Quinta</option>" +
    "<option value='5'" + (index == 5 ? "selected" : "") + ">Sexta</option>" +
    "<option value='6'" + (index == 6 ? "selected" : "") + ">Sábado</option>" +
    "<option value='7'" + (index == 7 ? "selected" : "") + ">Domingo</option>" +
    "</select>";
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: esta foi exatamente a maneira que eu pensei em fazer, só que iria dar mais código porque eu não conhecia esse `if inline`, detalhe, agora o array dias é desnecessario e como o retorno é string da para colocar o `===` e add '1' mas isso é detalhe.

Comment: Seria interessante usar a array `var dias = Array(` e fazer isso mais [DRY](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/129). Uma sugestão poderia ser: http://jsfiddle.net/2xb08pzd/6/