# Atualizar um elemento de uma lista genérica por um item específico

Tags: c#, .net, lista, genéricos

Como faço para atualizar um elemento específico de uma lista genérica localizando pelo ID e passar um objeto atualizado em seu lugar, atualizando o nome e o e-mail?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Aluno> aluno = new List<Aluno>{
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 1, Nome = "Cláudia",Email="claudia@email.com" },
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 2, Nome = "Pedro",Email="pedro@email.com" },
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 3, Nome = "Eduardo",Email="eduardo@email.com" }
        };

        Console.WriteLine("==================================");

        foreach (var item in aluno)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}\nNome: {1}\nEmail: {2}", item.AlunoId, item.Nome,item.Email);
            Console.WriteLine("==================================");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nLista Atualizada\n");

        int iElemento = 1;

        var elem = aluno.Where<Aluno>(a => a.AlunoId == iElemento).FirstOrDefault();
        int index = aluno.IndexOf(elem);

        aluno[index].Nome = "Cláudia Limeira";
        aluno[index].Email = "claudia_limeira@email.com";

        foreach (var item in aluno)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}\nNome: {1}\nEmail: {2}", item.AlunoId, item.Nome, item.Email);
            Console.WriteLine("==================================");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Aluno
{
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refiz o código dando uma solução mais geral, acredito que você possa tirar o que não precisa:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var alunos = new List<Aluno> {
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 1, Nome = "Cláudia", Email = "claudia@email.com" },
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 2, Nome = "Pedro",   Email = "pedro@email.com" },
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 3, Nome = "Eduardo", Email = "eduardo@email.com" }
        };
        ImprimeAlunos(alunos);
        while (true) {
            var id = 0;
            Write("Qual ID de aluno deseja modificar? (-1 para encerrar)");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out id)) {
                if (id == -1) break;
                var alunoAchado = alunos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AlunoId == id);
                if (alunoAchado != null) {
                    Write("Qual o novo nome? ");
                    alunoAchado.Nome = ReadLine();
                    Write("Qual o novo e-mail? ");
                    alunoAchado.Email = ReadLine();
                } else WriteLine("Id inválido tente outro");
            } else WriteLine("Id inválido tente outro");
        }
         WriteLine("Nova Lista");
        ImprimeAlunos(alunos);
    }
    
    static void ImprimeAlunos(List<Aluno> alunos) {
        WriteLine("==================================");
        foreach (var item in alunos) {
            WriteLine($"ID: {item.AlunoId}\nNome: {item.Nome}\nEmail: {item.Email}");
            WriteLine("==================================");
        }
    }
}

class Aluno {
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FkbEKP). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/88i9et). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/UpdateList.cs).

Note que no caso de estar fazendo uma busca usando LINQ o retorno é o próprio item, então não precisa usar índice para acessá-lo. O que for mudado no item encontrado se refletirá na lista de alunos.

No seu código o código usa o `Where` e o `FisrtOrDefault`. Isto é redundante já que o o segundo já faz o que o primeiro faz de forma mais adequada ao contexto (o primeiro tende ser mais lento). Aí o código recebe o item. O ideal é alterá-lo e você preferiu achar o índice dele para alterar pelo índice conforme foi informado na pergunta anterior. Só que neste caso não precisa, é trabalho desnecessário. A não ser que o problema exija que faça isto, o que eu duvido, mas aí seria melhor resolver de outra forma (retornando o índice e não o item).

Note também que usei um estilo mais moderno de codificação. Se tiver alguma dúvida específica peça esclarecimento ou abra uma pergunta se achar que o tema merece.

Dá para melhorar ainda mais, dá para validar mais coisas, mas isto é o básico.

Fiz uma outra [**versão sem usar LINQ**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/arKFxt). Ou seja, eu fiz o que o LINQ faria.

Comment: Eu não falei besteira quando falei em **tipo por referência** na minha resposta, né?

Comment: Não, está certinho.

Comment: Bigown, ficou ótimo, vou mercar como resposta!!! Você acha que a forma como fiz acabei usando muito código desnecessário? A minha ideia como eu passei na mensagem era de criar uma instância da classe aluno, passar os valores para as propriedades e em seguida localizar o elemento na lista e colocar esse objeto na posição do elemento desatualizado, fazendo isso de forma automática, mas acabei estendendo o código.

Comment: Quase nada de fato. Mas eu gosto de fazer o mais curto possível que mantenha a legibilidade. E gosto de usar as coisas mais modernas. Alguns não estão disponíveis em compiladores antigos, o que pode precisar de adaptação. Uma das coisas que certamente eu faria de qualquer forma no momento que houve duas impressões da lista, é transformar isto em método para atender o [DRY](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/101). Ou até mesmo para atender o princípio da [responsabilidade única](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Comment: Tem sempre várias formas de fazer. Se seu exercício exigisse fazer pelo índice, eu faria assim, mas não parece ser o caso. Se exigisse criar uma nova instância do `Aluno` e substituir a antiga pela nova, eu teria feito assim. Mas não está especificado isso na pergunta, acho que é livre para fazer como quiser, por isto optei pela mais simples e lógica.

Comment: @KellySoares eu vi que você trocou a aceitação da resposta, você sabe que só pode aceitar uma resposta? Votar pode em todas, mas aceitar só uma, quando você aceita a segunda, você troca o voto. Se ainda não tinha entendido isto dê uma revisada em todas suas perguntas e veja e não trocou a aceitação por acidente. Você pode aceitar qualquer achar melhor, isto é uma decisão só sua, mas tenha certeza que esta aceitando de fato o que escolheu.

Comment: Comentei sobre passar um objeto atualizado porque eu achei estranho a parte onde tive que passar valores propriedades por propriedades, este exemplo que fiz na verdade vou adaptar a um código que já recebe a classe aluno com as suas propriedades atualizada, o que preciso é lançar essa propriedade na lista para simplificar mais. As dúvidas que eu tinha era em localizar um item por ID e atualizar a lista com o objeto que já recebe as informações atualizada. Mas posso criar uma nova pergunta para finalizar essa última questão de passar o objeto direto para o elemento localizado.

Comment: Você fala em clicar no triângulo onde aceita a pergunta como útil ou no triângulo que aponta para cima e tem a opção abaixo marcar como resposta?

Comment: @KellySoares falo na marca de *check* verde, só pode uma por pergunta sua. Veja o [tour]. O triângulo pra cima e p/ baixo, é voto, esse você pode votar em tudo no site todo, não são nas suas perguntas, e se quer aprender sugiro ler outras perguntas, votar nelas, votar nas respostas que acha úteis. Tem muito material bom aqui pra aprender. Exemplo pra começar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29204/discussion-between-kelly-soares-and-bigown).

Answer (score 5):

Para localizar o item, você precisa fazer:

```
var item = aluno.First(x => x.Id == 1); //Localizando o aluno com id 1
```

Para atualizá-lo:

```
item.Nome = "Novo nome";
item.Email = "aluno@aluno.com";
```

Como `Aluno` é um [tipo por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101), ao alterar o objeto `item`, o objeto dentro da Lista também será atualizado.

Comment: Obrigada Jéferson mais uma vez!

Comment: Obrigado pela edição @bigown, eu estava mesmo procurando por essa questão.

Comment: Eu sei :) .....

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um crud pra cuidar da lista :) o/

tipo isso ó

```
    private List<Obj> listaDeObjetos = new List<Obj>();

    public void Add(Obj obj)
    {
        listaDeObjetos.Add(obj);
    }

    public Obj Get(int id)
    {
        return listaDeObjetos.Find(c => c.Id == id);
    }

    public void Remove(Obj obj)
    {
        listaDeObjetos.Remove(obj);
    }

    public void Update(Cart objQueVaiSerAtualizado)
    {
        var objQueVaiSerRemovido= Get(objQueVaiSerAtualizado.Id);
        Remove(objQueVaiSerRemovido);
        Add(objQueVaiSerAtualizado);
    }
```

como pra remover um objeto de uma lista é necessario passar o objeto, logo o update se torna o mais "complexo" dos metodos.

no metodo update: vc chama ele passando o objeto que vai ser atualizado, digamos que vc alterou o nome, que é uma propriedade do objeto e tal, ai vc passa o obj com o novo nome, dentro do metodo vc procura na lista utilizando o metodo Get passando o id do objeto que vai ser atualizado, o metodo get retorna o objeto que está na lista e não foi alterado o nome, com esse objeto vc passa para o metodo remove, que vai remover esse objeto desatualizado em sequida chama o add pra adicionar o objeto atualizado.

Comment: Obrigada Evilasio e desculpe pelo retorno. Só agora consegui acessar. Gostei da sua explicação!