# Preciso de uma outra solução para fazer esse código

Tags: javascript, html

Gente eu fiz um código para aparecer a palavra no final com o click, mas o meu código ficou muito extenso. Tem alguma outra solução pra fazer a mesma coisa?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Substituir</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="nome1" onclick="nome1()">Dinossauro</p>
    <p id="nome2" onclick="nome2()">Tubarao</p>
    <p id="nome3" onclick="nome3()">Ornitorrinco</p>
    <p id="nome4" onclick="nome4()">Gralha</p>

    <p id="recebe"></p>

    <script src="teste.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var botao = document.querySelector("p");

function nome1(){

    var selecionaTexto = document.querySelector("#nome1");
    var texto = selecionaTexto.textContent;

    var campoRecebe = document.querySelector("#recebe");
    campoRecebe.textContent = texto;

    console.log(texto);

};
function nome2(){

    var selecionaTexto = document.querySelector("#nome2");
    var texto = selecionaTexto.textContent;

    var campoRecebe = document.querySelector("#recebe");
    campoRecebe.textContent = texto;

    console.log(texto);

};
function nome3(){

    var selecionaTexto = document.querySelector("#nome3");
    var texto = selecionaTexto.textContent;

    var campoRecebe = document.querySelector("#recebe");
    campoRecebe.textContent = texto;

    console.log(texto);

};
function nome4(){

    var selecionaTexto = document.querySelector("#nome4");
    var texto = selecionaTexto.textContent;

    var campoRecebe = document.querySelector("#recebe");
    campoRecebe.textContent = texto;

    console.log(texto);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso de maneira mais organizada procurando padrões no código.

Podes por exemplo dar a mesma classe a todos os elementos que queres que tenham essa funcionalidade (exemplo em baixo). Podes também fazer de outras maneiras, filtrando elementos com um certo ID ou parte de ID. Mas depois a lógica é a mesma: adicionas um auscultador de evento ao elemento e o `this` dentro dessa função é o elemento clicado.

```
var nomes = document.querySelectorAll('.nome');
for (var i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
    nomes[i].addEventListener('click', buscarNome)
}

function buscarNome() {
    var texto = this.textContent;
    var campoRecebe = document.querySelector("#recebe");
    campoRecebe.textContent = texto;
    console.log(texto);
}
```

**Exemplo:** https://jsfiddle.net/su4kxrmz/

Quando fazes mudanças deste género, para evitar repetição de código diz-se [*tornar o código DRY*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/129)