# Não concatena o If

Tags: javascript

Galera, podem me ajudar... estou aprendendo a fazer um relógio com JavaScript...

Mas o if para concatenar o 0 na frente dos segundos, minutos e horas não está funcionando... não consigo encontrar o erro...

```
    var tempo=new Date();
    var hora=tempo.getHours();
    var min=tempo.getMinutes();
    var seg=tempo.getSeconds();

    var impressao=hora + ":" + min + ":" + seg;

    if(hora<10){
        hora="0" + tempo.getHours;
    }
    if(min<10){
        min="0" + tempo.getMinutes;
    }
    if (seg<10){
        seg="0" + tempo.getSeconds;
    }

    document.write(impressao);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vários erros. Coloque a linha que seta impressão antes do write e use () após o getHours etc.Assim:

```
var tempo=new Date();
var hora=tempo.getHours();
var min=tempo.getMinutes();
var seg=tempo.getSeconds();

if(hora<10){
    hora="0" + tempo.getHours();
}
if(min<10){
    min="0" + tempo.getMinutes();
}
if (seg<10){
    seg="0" + tempo.getSeconds();
}

var impressao=hora + ":" + min + ":" + seg;

document.write(impressao);
```

mas dá pra melhorar muito disso. Mas vou deixar vc descobrir como ;)

Comment: muito obrigado Nelson, me ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 0):

Você está declarando a variável impressão antes dos if's, assim ele está pegando os valores sem os zeros na frente. Coloque a declaração depois dos if's e imprima.

Answer (score 0):

Já tens uma resposta aceite, mas aqui fica outra, a meu ver mais limpa e mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/129).

Eu costumo usar uma função simples para isso:

```
function pad(s) {
    return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s;
}
```

Dessa maneira não repetes código, fica mais organizado.

Outra dica para organizar é fazer `[hora, min, seg].join(':');` em vêz de `hora + ":" + min + ":" + seg;`. Mais limpo e usa menos meória uma vez que concatenar strings gera uma cópia de cada substring que vai sendo concatenada. Repara que essa linha `var impressao = ...` tem de estar depois de acrescentares o `0`, para ele ser incluído nessa linha, senão como tens agora ele ignora essas ultimas linhas.

Assim o teu código podia ficar assim:

```
function pad(s) {
    return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s;
}

var tempo = new Date();
var hora = tempo.getHours();
var min = tempo.getMinutes();
var seg = tempo.getSeconds();

var impressao = [hora, min, seg].map(pad).join(':');
document.body.innerHTML = impressao;
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsq4w29m/