# Array não lido com índice definido no input

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

vejam abaixo o seguinte código:

```
<input type="text" id="task" name="task[]" value="100" />
<input type="text" id="task" name="task[]" value="110" />
<input type="text" id="task" name="task[]" value="120" />
```

E no jquery, faço a leitura do array normalmente:

```
$(function(){
var values = $("input[name='task\\[\\]']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

alert(values);
});
```

Agora, ao incluir o indice manual no array, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="text" id="task" name="task[1]" value="100" />
<input type="text" id="task" name="task[2]" value="110" />
<input type="text" id="task" name="task[3]" value="120" />
```

Neste caso, o jquery já não faz a leitura do array. O que deve ser feito para tornar possivel a leitura?

Comment: Qual o problema com o php?

Comment: O problema parece ser com a expressão regular que você está usando pra recuperar os Inputs: name='task[]' (omitindo os escapes: \\). Quando inseriu o número, ela deixou de ser válida. Tente substituir para: $("input[name='task\\\[.\\\]']"). Se funcionar, fique atento pois a expressão regular continua bem específica, e não funcionaria com um array maior com dois dígitos, como task[10] por exemplo.

Comment: Olá Newton, neste caso, você poderia me sugerir uma outra expressão regular mais adeaquada?

Comment: Esse vai pegar todos os inputs que comecem com task e tenham qualquer coisa em seguida: $("input[name='task.*']")

Answer (score 1):

Nesse cenário não vejo sentido o uso do índice sobre a propriedade `name`, visto que existe outro problema nesse `HTML`. Você está dando o mesmo `id` para mais de um elemento na sua página. O `id`, como seu nome diz, é um identificador único, não deveria ter mais de um na mesma página. Faria mais sentido você trabalhar da seguinte maneira:

```
<input type="text" id="task[1]" name="task[]" value="100" />
<input type="text" id="task[2]" name="task[]" value="110" />
<input type="text" id="task[3]" name="task[]" value="120" />
```

Caso você não pretenda trabalhar diretamente com os `ids`, também lhe aconselho remover essa informação. Se algo não vai ser usado, não coloque essa informação desnecessariamente tentando prever o seu uso futuro, isso não é algo recomendado (existe um princípio que se fala disto: [YAGNI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23052/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-princ%C3%ADpios-dry-kiss-e-yagni))