# Como evitar repetição a escutar mudanças em propriedades de um componente?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dry

Quando preciso de reagir a mudanças de *N* propriedades para a mesma callback dou por mim a usar algo assim:

```
watch: {
    propriedadeA(){
        this.reagir();
    },
    propriedadeB(){
        this.reagir();
    },
    propriedadeC(){
        this.reagir();
    }
}
```

Há alguma maneira de ser mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/129) nesta abordagem?

Answer (score 8):

```
this.$watch(vm => [vm.x, vm.y, vm.z].join(), val => {
  // ...
})
```

Depois de ter escrito a resposta original (em baixo), o criador do Vue.js [sugeriu esta maneira](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/844#issuecomment-335026928) (em cima) ainda mais limpa.

**Resposta original:**

Encontrei uma [solução interessante aqui](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/844#issuecomment-265315349). Na verdade nessa thread há uma ideia de plugin/mixin, mas achei esta sugestão que coloco em baixo bem simples e interessante.

Tendo em conta que o Vue.js regista quais as propriedades acedidas quando um propriedade `computed` é chamada podemos confiar no Vue.js para só correr um método/propriedade que seja `computed` quando um dos seus valores necessários tiver mudado.

Assim, se tivermos algo como `return a, b, c;` num dado `computed` o código vai chamar `a`, `b` e `c` e o Vue.js vai registar que esse `computed` precisa desses valores. E portanto vai chamar/correr esse `computed` quando o *setter* de um desses valores mudar. Para garantir que podemos usar isso associado a um `watch`, basta retornar `Date.now()` por exemplo para o valor final desse `computed` ser sempre novo/único.

Assim podemos fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo e organizar o código melhor:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      mudancaConstante: 0,
      valorA: 0,
      valorB: 100,
      valorC: "constante",
      contadorABC: 0
    };
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => this.mudancaConstante++, 250);
    setInterval(() => this.valorA++, 2500);
    setInterval(() => this.valorB++, 1500);
  },
  // a parte interessante é daqui para baixo
  computed: {
    observadorABC() {
      return this.valorA, this.valorB, this.valorC, new Date();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    observadorABC() {
      this.contadorABC++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>this.mudancaConstante: {{mudancaConstante}}</p>
  <p>this.contadorABC: {{contadorABC}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: esqueceu de aceitar a sua resposta? hehe