# Qual é a diferença entre usar variável e passar parâmetro direto?

Tags: php, javascript, variáveis, parâmetros

Eu queria saber a real diferença e  entre

```
$sql = 'select * from tbl_blablabla';
$result = $connect->prepare(sql);
```

e

```
$result = $connect->prepare('select * from tbl_blabla');
```

Não apenas nesse caso específico, mas vários outros casos que eu já vi um monte de gente fazendo um monte de variável para receber parâmetros sendo que se digita menos no exemplo 2, isso afeta a performance? Segurança? Se afeta a segurança, o que exatamente acontece?

Comment: Geralmente é por legibilidade ou tratamento de erros, acho que não há um porquê específico. Por exemplo, poderia haver um erro na linha `$sql` que se você colocasse diretamente na linha `$result` a dificuldade de encontrar o erro é maior. É só um exemplo.

Comment: Não afeta performance e nem afeta segurança. Só afeta seu código. Eu sou um dos que prefere usar o primeiro exemplo. Para mim é mais legível e prático, caso eu precise usar a mesma variável mais tarde, ela já existe, é só usar.

Comment: @Francisco, tem razão, há ainda o reaproveitamento que esqueci de mencionar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nesse exemplo a diferença é que escreveu uma linha a mais no primeiro.

Há zero vantagens aí, e a única razão que vejo as pessoas usando assim é que não sabem [o que é uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) e para que ela serve. Claro, o gosto da pessoa pode ser outro motivo, mas aí não é razão.

Se tivesse uma expressão mais complexa eu até entenderia que se fizesse antes e guardasse em uma variável com nome significativo. Um nome que não é informativo ou informa a obviedade não aumenta a legibilidade.

Se o valor fosse usado em outros lugares aí tem o exato motivo para uma variável existir.

Fazer algo porque um dia pode precisar viola o [princípio do YAGNI, e de uma certa forma do KISS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/101). Tendo um IDE bom mudar a expressão para uma variável se precisar é a coisa mais simples que tem.

Não é para poupar código, é para simplificar o código. Colocar a declaração/definição do que vai usar mais próximo possível de onde é usado costuma dar mais legibilidade. Código longo é mais difícil de acompanhar. Fora a semântica que se existe uma variável é porque deve ser usado em vários lugares. Código é expressão, quando expressa errado passa a ideia errada e torna o código convoluto.

Dependendo da linguagem há diferença de performance e até consumo de memória.

Nunca faça nada sem saber porque está fazendo. Não vá no automático, não siga regras que outros disseram que é bom. Procure o que é bom para você, mas faça isso com a consciência de escolha.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Resposta muito boa. Você disse que tem linguagens em que isso pode consumir memória, isso tem algum motivo? Onde se ganha nisso?

Comment: Tem linguagens que vão alocar o espaço para a variável e colocar o resultado lá e depois vai copiar esse resultado onde precisa, isso é custo. Algumas linguagens conseguem fazer a variável desaparecer já que ela não é necessária e poderá usar o registrador direto.

Comment: Exatamente como vc disse no post, as pessoas parecem não entender a função de uma variável no código, sempre acreditei que tinha algo a ver com segurança que a variável era capaz de encapsular e proteger as informações. Achava mesmo estranho o fato de uma variável(o próprio nome diz) receber apenas 1 único valor estático no código todo.

Answer (score 1):

É basicamente a mesma coisa que:

```
int numero = 1;
printf("%d",numero);
```

e

```
printf("1");
```

A diferença é que no primeiro você teve que declarar a variável (e armazenar memoria para um inteiro, 4 bytes) e no segundo não.