# Mesclar duas funcionalidades

Tags: git

Tenho 1 branch no meu projeto

```
1 - Master
```

Criei mais 1 branch e desenvolvi 1 feature. Agora tenho 2 branchs

```
1 - Master 
2 - feature1
```

Comecei a desenvolver outra feature e agora tenho 3 branchs

```
1 - Master
2 - feature1
3 - feature2
```

Finalizei a primeira feature e agora tenho 2 branchs

```
1 - Master
2 - feature2
```

Mas agora preciso da feature1 no branch da feature2, pois uma funcionalidade da feature2 depende de uma funcionalidade que foi implementada na feature1.

Qual o procedimento correto pra fazer o merge dos branchs nesse caso, sem que eu precise fazer um merge de tudo no master?
Estou usando o gitflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está num fluxo de desenvolvimento chamado *feature-branch workflow*. É bom conhecer esses nomes porque assim você pode procurar por coisas mais especializadas nisso no Google.

Eu gosto bastante da descrição da Atlassian desse *worflow*: https://www.atlassian.com/br/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow

Nesse caso específico, houve um problema de levantamento de requisitos antes de se começar o trabalho. Por quê? Porque a `feature2` só deveria ter sido implementada *após* um código básico proveniente da `feature1`. Talvez não fosse possível resolver esse problema de requisitos antes de começar a implementar, porque talvez só se percebesse essa dependência durante a escrita do código.

Existem algumas alternativas para a sua situação. A mais "básica" e que funciona para quase tudo (não a melhor sempre, entretanto), é fazer

```bsh
$ git fetch && git merge origin/Master
```

no branch `feature2`. Assim, você garante que o código requisito está no lugar correto.

Outra alternativa é diminuir a entrega. Como assim?

Bem, se foi possível começar o código da `feature2` **antes** de existir o código da `feature1`, então isso significa que tem uma parte da `feature2` que é **independente** da `feature1`. Nesse caso, você poderia fazer um *pull request*/*merge request* do trecho de código independente. Ele não entregará a *feature* inteira, mas dará um passo importante nela. Só depois de misturado esse código você poderá dar seguimento na `feature2-codigo-dependente-da-feautre1` em cima do branch `Master` já mergeado com essa primeira parte da `feature`.

Existe outra abordagem que é tentar manter os *feature branches* todos partindo da cabeça estável, mas para isso é necessário dar constantes `rebase` após cada `merge`. Conheço uma equipe que trabalha (mais ou menos) assim (mas com *giflow*, não *feature-branch workflow*), o histórico de commits linear fica lindo, mas como eles trabalham com lançamentos "futuros" (manutenções na versão `3.X` geram `rebase` na `4.X` [primeiro futuro] que gera `rebase` na `5.X` [segundo futuro] que gera `rebase` na `6.X` [terceiro e último futuro]), fica confuso retro-referência de commits.

Particularmente **eu**, como revisor de código, prefiro **sempre** a solução que gere a maior quantidade de `merge requests` com o menor diferencial de código em cada `merge request` individual. Claro, desde que cada `merge request` seja autocontido e autossuficiente, e que também seja realmente uma unidade lógica de mudança. Talvez essas mudanças individualmente ofendam temporariamente o [YAGNI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/64969), mas se a funcionalidade como um todo precisa entrar, a versão estável do código não ofenderá o YAGNI por muito tempo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente sincronizar sua branch `feature2` com a branch `master` utilizando os seguintes comandos:

```
$ git checkout feature2
$ git pull origin master
```

O fato de você realizar o `pull` da sua branch `master` para a `feature2` irá sincronizar sua branch com a `master`, e consequentemente você terá o código da sua `feature1` na `feature2` (visto que a `feature1` já está na `master`).

Essa operação pode apresentar conflitos, após a resolução você deve gerar um commit para finalização do merge:

```
git commit
```